# How to save an np.array on google drive using colab?

Tags: python, numpy, google-colaboratory

I write a program in Colab and the result of the program is np.arrays. Please tell me how to save the array to a file, and then how to read it from the file?

I read this instruction: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=S7c8WYyQdh5i

As a result, I figured out how to connect to a google drive and how to create and upload a text file there in the directory I need.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

uploaded = drive.CreateFile({'title': 'Sample upload.txt'})
uploaded.SetContentString('Sample upload file content')
uploaded.Upload()
print('Uploaded file with ID {}'.format(uploaded.get('id')))
```

I also know that you can save the array as a text file like this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
np.savetxt ("array.txt", a, fmt = "% s")
```

But I can't figure out how to save this text file to google drive. And how to read an array from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will put the file in the top level of your Drive (https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive):

```
import numpy as np

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

with open('/content/drive/My Drive/array.txt', 'w') as f:
    np.savetxt(f, a)
```

You can then use this to read the array back into `numpy`:

```
with open('/content/drive/My Drive/array.txt', 'r') as f:
    a = np.loadtxt(f)
```